# Postgresql sorting mixed alphanumeric data

Tags: postgresql, sorting, alphanumeric

Running this query:

```
select name from folders order by name
```

returns these results:

```
alphanumeric
a test
test 20
test 19
test 1
test 10
```

But I expected:

```
a test
alphanumeric
test 1
test 10
test 19
test 20
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: It looks weird: `'test 20' < 'test 19'`. What `LC_COLLATE` you have by examinating `SHOW lc_collate;` ? I have `en_US.UTF-8` and it returns exactly wanted output with `ORDER BY name ASC`.

Comment: I get the same thing, too.  I just did `select 'alphanumeric' < 'a test'` and got `f`.

Comment: for the record, i posted an answer pointing you to the manual entry for collation.  it was donwvoted as not being huggy-lovey enough so i deleted it.  but i think you should start there.

Comment: @andrew cooke: I didn't downvote, that was good point, collation is responsible for ordering, however _per-column collation_, which could be useful here is supported only since Postgres 9.1.

Comment: Hello, thk for your comments... SHOW lc_collate; is returning es_SV.UTF-8 (I live in El Salvador)

Comment: you can set collation for the entire db on creation.  it's not clear that wouldn't work here - typically people want ordering to work everywhere in the same way, no?

Comment: I installed `es_SV.UTF-8` on Debian, then created new db with that locale and surprisingly I have such output: `'alphanumeric', 'a test', 'test 1', 'test 10', 'test 19', 'test 20'` (same as for `en_US.UTF-8`).

Comment: Consider others values (this is not so clear if is go about numbers an others non alphabetical chars). Something like this: '3','50','100', '_9', '1b','2a','2 x', 'My Value 1','my Value 2', 'my value 3','  Others  '

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can simply cast `name` column to [`bytea`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html) data type allowing collate-agnostic ordering:

```
SELECT name
FROM folders
ORDER BY name::bytea;
```

Result:

```
     name     
--------------
 a test
 alphanumeric
 test 1
 test 10
 test 19
 test 20
(6 rows)
```

Comment: This fixes sorting with leading spaces that `TRIM` would not solve.

Comment: Be careful, as it's still alphanumeric (meaning "3" will come after "20")

Answer (score 23):

All of this methods sorted my selection in alphabetical order:

```
test 1
test 10
test 2
test 20
```

This solution worked for me (lc_collate: 'ru_RU.UTF8'):

```
SELECT name
FROM folders
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(name FROM '([0-9]+)')::BIGINT ASC, name;

test 1
test 2
test 10
test 20
```

Answer (score 15):

```sql
select * from "public"."directory" where "directoryId" = 17888 order by
COALESCE(SUBSTRING("name" FROM '^(\d+)')::INTEGER, 99999999),
SUBSTRING("name" FROM '[a-zA-z_-]+'),
COALESCE(SUBSTRING("name" FROM '(\d+)$')::INTEGER, 0),
"name";
```

**NOTE:** Escape the regex as you need, in some languages, you will have to add one more "\".

In my Postgres DB, name column contains following, when I use simple order by name query:

- 1
- 10
- 2
- 21
- A
- A1
- A11
- A5
- B
- B2
- B22
- B3
- M 1
- M 11
- M 2

**Result of Query, After I have modified it:**

- 1
- 2
- 10
- 21
- A
- A1
- A5
- A11
- B
- B2
- B3
- B22
- M 1
- M 2
- M 11

Answer (score 8):

You may be able to manually sort by splitting the text up in case there is trailing numerals, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM sort_test
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(text FROM '^(.*?)( \\d+)?$'),
         COALESCE(SUBSTRING(text FROM ' (\\d+)$')::INTEGER, 0);
```

This will sort on column text, first by all characters optionally excluding an ending space followed by digits, then by those optional digits.

Worked well in my test.

**Update** fixed the string-only sorting with a simple coalesce (duh).

Comment: Why the downvote?  It works, and solves the situation.  It's not the *best* solution, but it doesn't involve changing the database structure.  At least comment if you feel the need to downvote.

Comment: -1 for bizarre kluge that doesn't solve the real problem. (What about strings with multiple spaces and/or numbers?) See the comments above about collations.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a *bizarre kludge*.  It adds the ability to sort trailing numbers numerically, without requiring a specific version of PG.  It handles *trailing* numbers very well, so works well for sequentially numbered folders.  It handles multiple spaces, because it's only checking to ensure that there is at least one space before the trailing digits.  If you tried it, you'd see it worked, instead of assuming.

Comment: Not working for texts like: "H1C11", because it order for the first number, not for the tailing

Answer (score 5):

OverZealous answer helped me but didn't work if the string in the database begun with numbers followed by additional characters.

The following worked for me:

```
SELECT name
FROM folders
ORDER BY
COALESCE(SUBSTRING(name FROM '^(\\d+)')::INTEGER, 99999999),
SUBSTRING(name FROM '^\\d* *(.*?)( \\d+)?$'),
COALESCE(SUBSTRING(name FROM ' (\\d+)$')::INTEGER, 0),
name;
```

So this one:

1. Extracts the first number in the string, or uses 99999999.
2. Extracts the string that follows the possible first number.
3. Extracts a trailing number, or uses 0.

Answer (score 3):

A Vlk's answer above helped me a lot, but it sorted items only by the numeric part, which in my case came second. My data was like (desk 1, desk 2, desk 3 ...) a string part, a space and a numeric part. The syntax in A Vlk's answer returned the data sorted by the number, and at that it was the only answer from the above that did the trick. However when the string part was different, (eg desk 3, desk 4, table 1, desk 5...) table 1 would get first from desk 2. I fixed this using the syntax below:

```
    ...order by SUBSTRING(name,'\\w+'), SUBSTRINGname FROM '([0-9]+)')::BIGINT ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tor's last SQL worked for me. However if you are calling this code from php you need add extra slashes.

```
SELECT name
FROM folders
ORDER BY
COALESCE(SUBSTRING(name FROM '^(\\\\d+)')::INTEGER, 99999999),
SUBSTRING(name FROM '^\\\\d* *(.*?)( \\\\d+)?$'),
COALESCE(SUBSTRING(name FROM ' (\\\\d+)$')::INTEGER, 0),
name;
```