# relative position of digits and ':' in postgres collating sequence

Tags: postgresql

say I have a table 't1' with a string column 'name'. And I have names 'n1','n2','n9' and 'n:'. If I do

```
select * from t1 orderby name asc
```

I expect

```
n1
n2
n9
n:
```

Given that ':' comes after '9' in ASCII, but instead, I get

```
n:
n1
n2
n9
```

Which is a surprise. Is there something I need to do to say 'use ASCII as the collating sequence for basic ASCII chars'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, this is a collation issue

```
SELECT *    FROM t1 ORDER BY name COLLATE "POSIX";
```

This is a list of exapmle collations in case that collation  have listed, SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN does not work

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/collation.html

Comment: "collation "sql_latin1_general_cp850_bin" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist", I assume because that is a MySQL doc u pointed me at

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated it with a link to the collation page for postgres, it also says "C" should work if but those should also be the default.

Comment: If that doesnt work i just found a similar issue involving spaces where they by cast the object to byte array for sorting.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537982/incorrect-sort-collation-order-with-spaces-in-postgresql-9-4