# django rest_frameworks orderingfilter is wrong?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm new to python/django and I'm running into a weird sorting problem.

I'm importing and using **OrderingFilter** in a base model class. Then I declare **ordering_fields** on the model class with the field to use for ordering. For instance, I'm using **name** so that when I make a URL request with a query param (https://something.com/api/v3/campaigns/?ordering=name), I expect that list of results to be sorted alphabetically by name.

If my list of names is:

- Pitched Campaign
- Pitch Rejected Campaign
- Awesome Campaign

I expect the filtered call to return:

1. Awesome Campaign
2. Pitch Rejected Campaign
3. Pitched Campaign

Instead, I get:

1. Awesome Campaign
2. Pitched Campaign
3. Pitch Rejected Campaign

It's as if the OrderingFilter ignores the whitespace in those strings and orders that way. It's the only thing I can think of to explain why:

*Pitched Campaign* (pitchedcampaign)
comes before
*Pitch Rejected Campaign* (pitchrejectedcampaign)

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Can you provide the code where you implement `ordering` and `ordering_fields`

Comment: @scharette Thanks for responding, but I think I found what my problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537982/incorrect-sort-collation-order-with-spaces-in-postgresql-9-4)