# PostgreSQ: JOIN SELECT and ORDER hidden

Tags: postgresql, union, sortedlist

A database table "myTable" has the field "category";

```
SELECT DISTINCT "category" FROM "myTable" ORDER BY "category" ASC;
   A-Class
   T-Class
   Z-Class
```

OK, now I have to add a line 'undefined', e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "category" FROM "myTable"  
UNION SELECT '>undefined<' 
ORDER BY "category" ASC;
   A-Class
   T-Class
   >undefined<
   Z-Class
```

I need the 'undefined' as first entry in the list and tried several characters like .,-_<>! at the first place, but all are ignored and the u is taken for the order.

Is there any simple option to achieve this, without showing a second column in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a subquery or a CTE:

```
with sortme as (
  select distinct category, category as category_sort 
    from "myTable"
  union 
  select 'undefined', ''
)
select category
  from sortme
 order by category_sort;
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

You can type

`order by case "category" when 'undefined' then 1 else 0 end, "category";`

With special characters such as `>` before `undefined`, you could also [cast category to bytea or use explicit collation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34538337/653539).

Comment: Thank you, order by case is a good proposal and shorter.Unfurtunately, in some of my cases the text to be ORDERed is a SubSELECT of another table and I could not get this to work in combination with the UNION.