# Sort Postgres VARCHAR as Numeric and String Last

Tags: postgresql

I have a column of type VARCHAR(15).
I want to sort it as if it were numbers, but if it has a letter, it is last in alphabetical order.

I have the data:

```
1
12
2
21
ABC13
ABC23
```

I tried:

```
NULLIF(regexp_replace(column, '\D', '', 'g'), '')::int
```

I expected:

```
1
2
12
21
ABC13
ABC23
```

But, actually resulted:

```
1
2
12
ABC13
21
ABC23
```

Comment: You're looking for a "natural sort". There's several answers on this site, see if one is acceptable.

Comment: One of decisions is fill some zerros before your number like lpad(nullif(regexp_replace(column, '\D', '', 'g'), ''), 10, '0')::int

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. If you need to sort only strings with digits and "ignore" alphanumeric strings sorting:

```
SELECT * 
FROM string_data
ORDER BY CASE WHEN string_value LIKE '^[0-9]+$'
         THEN CAST(string_value as integer)
         ELSE NULLIF(regexp_replace(string_value, '\D', '9', 'g'), '')::int
         END;
```

- `string_value LIKE '^[0-9]+$'` checks that given string consists of only digits
- `regexp_replace(string_value, '\D', '9', 'g')` replaces all the letters (`\D`) in given string with a digit `9` to arrange string with letters and digits in the end of a result tuple.
- as all the branches of a `CASE` should return the same datatype, all the letters are suggested to be replaced by `9`. Therefore there is no natural sort by letters if a string contains any letters.

And the result looks like:

```
 2
 12
 21
 abc13
 ABC13
 abc23
 ABC23
 abc32
```

#### 2. If you need to sort numeric values first, and then sort alphanumeric strings:

This query manipulates with column order in this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM string_data 
ORDER BY COALESCE(SUBSTRING(string_value FROM '^(\d+)$')::INTEGER, 99999999999),
         SUBSTRING(string_value FROM '[a-zA-z_-]+'),
         COALESCE(SUBSTRING(string_value FROM '(\d+)$')::INTEGER, 0),
         string_value;
```

- `COALESCE(SUBSTRING(string_value FROM '^(\d+)$')::INTEGER, 99999999999)` firstly, we retrieve strings consisting of only digits and put them in the first place in a result tuple because these strings have temporary value `99999999999` due to `COALESCE`. The regex `^(\d+)$` allows to do that.
- `SUBSTRING(string_value FROM '[a-zA-z_-]+')` secondly, we retrieve strings which start with letters.
- `COALESCE(SUBSTRING(string_value FROM '(\d+)$')::INTEGER, 0)` then, we retrieve **alphanumeric** strings which end with a number such as `ABC123` and put them after all the sorted numbers.

So the result looks like:

```
 2
 12
 21
 1a
 1ab
 1ab
 abc13
 abc23
 abc32
 ABC13
 ABC23
 3f
 2r
```

The second approach is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57427177/20666497).

Here is the [sql fiddle](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3yuy4b85p).

Comment: The use of a regex needs `~` not `LIKE`, making it: `string_value ~ '^[0-9]+$'`

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Albina was helpful (just remember to use `~` not `LIKE`) but I wanted all values that were integers-as-strings sorted numerically at the start of the result set, and all non-integer values sorted lexicographically at the end of the result set.

You can do that by left padding:

```sql
order by
    (CASE WHEN maybe_int_string ~ '^[0-9]+$' -- match int-as-string only
     THEN LPAD(maybe_int_string, 5, '0')     -- order int-as-string numerically at the start
     ELSE LPAD(maybe_int_string, 5, '9')     -- sort non-integers, grouped at the end
     END)`
```

In this way, `3` becomes `00003`, while `12` becomes `00012`, so those sort as you'd expect (not 12 then 3), and `bob` becomes `99bob` and gets stuck at the end, where it deserves.