How to Sort Alphanumeric Values?
I have a table and some example data:
CREATE TABLE alphanumeric
(
       alphanum varchar
);

INSERT INTO alphanumeric VALUES
('1'),
('A1'),
('A2'),
('A11'),
('2'),
('AB1'),
('AB2'),
('AB11'),
('11'),
('C3'),
('C4'),
('C33'),
('111');

Now I want to sort alphanumerically as:
1
2
11
111
A1
A2
A11
AB1
AB2
AB11
C3
C4
C33

But when I tried:
SELECT alphanum
FROM alphanumeric
ORDER BY alphanum;

That's not the result I expected:
1
11
111 
2 <-
A1
A11 <-
A2
AB1
AB11 <-
AB2
C3
C33 <-
C4

How should I do? It would be greatly appreciated if anyone can help.(BTW,
the database I use supports the majority of PostgreSQL syntax, so you can also use PostgreSQL for demo)

This question is similar to: Postgresql sorting mixed alphanumeric data. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.   (BTW: especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57427177/724039 )

I tried those 7 answers but only 1 got the result I wanted, thanks anyway

We can use regular expressions to first sort by the leading letters, followed by the trailing digits:
SELECT alphanum
FROM alphanumeric
ORDER BY
    SUBSTRING(alphanum FROM '^[A-Z]+'),
    SUBSTRING(alphanum FROM '[0-9]+$')::int;

